# Why Do People Continue Using Expensive Payment Services Like Paypal And Western Union

Tags: financial-literacy, bank-account, foreign-exchange, interest-rate

Paypal - the 'industry standard' for online payments makes this opportunity inaccessible to Africans in most cases. Most, who qualify to be a part of the workforce for some internet companies are not able to receive payments simply because we can't receive payments with Paypal accounts.

With Western Union, there are different charges depending on how the sender funds the payment either with a bank transfer, cash, credit or debit card and how the recipient accesses the money. All do have exorbitant charges which can go as high as 7 - 9%

Comment: I never knew **employees** got paid using PayPal.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better if there was an alternative proposed. I was expecting at the end a sentence with, everyone could just use X instead, which is cheaper!

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be a question that has a useful, definitive answer. I might suggest that people who choose platforms like Paypal for their Western businesses rarely consider the impact of those choices on people in Africa, but that would be (a) just opinion, and (b) not help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> With Western Union, there are different charges depending on how the sender funds the payment either with a bank transfer, cash, credit or debit card and how the recipient accesses the money.

What's really happening here is there are different charges depending on the risk of fraud and charge back in the input.  Different types of payment carry different levels of fraud and charge back risk which Western Union manages by charging an increased or additional fee for those sorts of inputs.

Western Union charges what it charges because it can.

Answer (score 1):

Retailers and websites asking for donations use PayPal to accept money because some people don't trust most websites with their credit card numbers, fearing that these sites might store their credit card information insecurely